# SQL DENSE_RANK not suitable because of existing table- how to get min/max dates in sequence when val changes

Tags: sql-server-2008, max, min, seq, dense-rank

I have an existing @table

```
ID  Date    Val
1   2014-10-01  1
2   2014-10-02  1
3   2014-10-03  1
4   2014-10-04  1
5   2014-10-05  1
6   2014-10-06  1
7   2014-10-07  1
8   2014-10-08  1
9   2014-10-09  1
```

The Date sequence is of importance.
I need to see the first and last date for each Val sequence:

```
Select Val,MIN([Date]) as A, MAX([Date]) as B
        from @T
        Group by Val

   Val  From        To
    1   2014-10-01  2014-10-09
```

The Val column now changes for 3 of these entries:

```
Update @T set Val = 2 where [ID] between 3 and 5
```

and returns:

```
ID  Date    Val
1   2014-10-01  1
2   2014-10-02  1
3   2014-10-03  2
4   2014-10-04  2
5   2014-10-05  2
6   2014-10-06  1
7   2014-10-07  1
8   2014-10-08  1
9   2014-10-09  1
```

How do I get SQL to return the min/max dates per sequence?
I need to show :
i.e.

```
1   2014-10-01  2014-10-02
2   2014-10-03  2014-10-05
1   2014-10-06  2014-10-09
```

If I run the normal Min/Max query, I get

```
1   2014-10-01  2014-10-09
2   2014-10-03  2014-10-05
```

Which does not show me that the val was 1 for 1st period,2 for 2nd period
and again 1 for 3rd period

```
declare @T table(ID int,[Date] date,Val int)
Insert Into @T(ID,[Date],Val)
 values(1,'2014/10/01', 1),
(2,'2014/10/02',    1),
(3,'2014/10/03',    1),
(4,'2014/10/04',    1),
(5,'2014/10/05',    1),
(6,'2014/10/06',    1),
(7,'2014/10/07',    1),
(8,'2014/10/08',    1),
(9,'2014/10/09',    1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Val,Min(Date) Min_Date,Max(Date) Max_Date 
FROM
(
SELECT ID,Date,Val,SUM(NewVal) OVER (order by ID) AS NewVal
FROM
    (
    SELECT ID,Date,Val,CASE WHEN Val<>LAG(Val, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END NewVal
    FROM @T
    ) I
) O
GROUP BY NewVal,Val
ORDER BY Min_Date
```

I adopted the answer from a previous answer to one of my own questions https://stackoverflow.com/a/21635529/1181412

Basically you're using the LAG function to compare the value of the previous row. When it's different you make it a 1, otherwise you use 0. Then you wrap that in a running sum which only increments every time NewVal goes up by 1. The result of the query matches what you're looking for.

The order of the records is obviously very important to this answer. So depending on your specific needs you may need to adjust the OVER clauses.

**Edit**

Per the comments this is an alternative answer which doesn't use LAG so it works in SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT Val,Min(Date) Min_Date,Max(Date) Max_Date 
FROM
(
SELECT ID,Date,Val,SUM(NewVal) OVER (order by ID) AS NewVal
FROM
    (
    SELECT M.ID,M.Date,M.Val,CASE WHEN M.Val<>L.Val THEN 1 ELSE 0 END NewVal
    FROM @T M
    LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT ID,Date,Val,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by ID)+1 NewRowId
        FROM @T
        ) L ON M.ID=L.NewRowId
    ) I
) O
GROUP BY NewVal,Val
ORDER BY Min_Date
```

Comment: Briliant thanks, I was not aware of LAG - this was a great answer and great for learning new things

Comment: OK i tested on SQL fiddle last night (which only had SQL 2014), but back at work on 2008, i see LAG only came with SQL 2012...  
  select t.Val,MIN(t.date),MAX(tnext.date)
from @T t join
     @T tnext
     on t.id = tnext.id - 1 and
      t.Val <> tnext.val
      group by 
      t.val                              back to the drawing board for me

Comment: Ah sorry. I will update my answer in a bit however you can accomplish the same in 2008. Just create a new set of row numbers offset by one. When you left join, it will be the equivalent of a lag.